# I'm new to Django Rest_Framework. I am trying to implement a function-based view but facing problem with the put method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to know how to access a particular object given a particular ID, and then update it. I'm currently getting the "405 method not allowed" error.

Is it possible to access an object via an ID, as mentioned above, or do I have to approach the problem in a different way?

My code is as currently as follows:

views.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from home.models import example
from home.serializers import exampleSerializer

@api_view(['GET', ])
def exampleview(request):
    try:
        ex=example.objects.all()
    except example.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method=="GET":
        serializer=exampleSerializer(ex, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['PUT', ])
def exampleputview(request):
    try:
        ex1=example.objects.get(id=id)
    except example.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method=="PUT":
        serializer=exampleSerializer(ex1, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('home/',views.exampleview),
    url('home/<int:id>/',views.exampleputview),
]
```

Comment: below answer should work or show your postman image

Answer (score 1):

PUT method need an id value, as you mentioned in URL,

Try putting **id** in your function params

```
@api_view(['PUT', ])
def exampleputview(request, id):
    try:
        ex1=example.objects.get(id=id)
    except example.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method=="PUT":
        serializer=exampleSerializer(ex1, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```